# Is creating an instance of a fragment inside an activity and reusing it bad coding practice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

There is one activity and two fragments.
You can switch to the other fragment by pressing a button (in the action bar in the optionsMenu).
By pressing the button the fragment is being replaced by the respective other fragment.

To make sure that the right fragment is being put into the fragment container, first, the currently displayed fragment has to be identified and then replaced.

```
when(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("test")!!.id) {
    foodListFragment.id -> {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,consumedFoodListFragment,"test")
            .commit()
    }
    consumedFoodListFragment.id -> {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container,foodListFragment,"test")
            .commit()
    }
}
```

One of the problems I encountered was that the fragment.id is dependent on the instance and not fixed, therefore I created two instances in the Main Activity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val foodListFragment by lazy { FoodListFragment() }
    private val consumedFoodListFragment by lazy { ConsumedFoodListFragment() }

    ...
}
```

(1) The main question I have is: Is this bad practice? My assumption would be yes, because as there is a reference to the fragment inside the Main Activity, the fragment lifecycle is dependent on the activity lifecycle and this is wrong as the fragment's lifecycle should be independend from the activity one's? Is this reasoning correct?

(2) Another question is: what would be a more elegant solution to this problem (identifying which fragment is currently displayed and replacing it)?

Comment: (2) How about `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("test") is FoodListFragment`? The `is FoodListFragment` can also be used as condition in the `when` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question i would say.

> 1) Fragment's lifecycle indeed depends on the activity of the life
>   cycle then can't exist without them. And yes it is a bad practice
>   given your use case. In my opinion, this is bad practice to save the
>   instance in the activity but it's fine also in some cases where your
>   users are visiting very frequently these fragments and you don't want
>   to recreate them every time and maintain their state and since there
>   are only 2 fragments so it's fine.
>
> 2) There is a fragment manager to do so here are below methods by
>   which we can find some fragment that is currently live right now.

1) Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.

```
findFragmentById(int id)

//example
getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

2) Finds a fragment that was identified by the given tag either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction.

```
findFragmentByTag(String tag)

 //example
getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_first");
```

3) Get a list of all fragments that are currently added to the FragmentManager.

```
getFragments()
```

Note: Also note if there is no heavy work getting done in the fragments you can consider them recreating instead.